# How can I programmatically select an AutoCompleteTextView?

Tags: android, keyboard, autocompletetextview

So I want to be able to programmatically "select" an `AutoCompleteTextView` in my application, as in make the cursor begin blinking over the textview and have the keyboard appear, as if the user had just pressed the view for input.

I wasn't able to find anything on this, and using `myTextView.setSelected(true)` did not seem to do anything (based on the fact that no cursor appeared on the textview, and the keyboard did not appear), so I'm not sure where to go at this point. Any advice would be awesome.

UPDATE:
When you requestFocus() on an AutoCompleteTextView, a blinking cursor does not appear. Certainly the view has focus, but it does not have a blinking cursor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution to anybody whom may be interested. The View literally has a setCursorVisible function, which shows the cursor. For some reason, setting the focus on an AutoCompleteTextView doesn't automatically do this.

Answer (score 0):

In order to select the auto complete text view please call

`myTextView.requestFocus()`

in your **onCreate** method.

Comment: This also does not appear to work, oddly. Nothing occurs on the AutoCompleteTextView

Comment: what is the value of windowSoftInputMode of your activity in your Manifest? i tested it on my side and it works..

Comment: windowSoftInputMode is not set in my manifest, however when I manually press the textview, the keyboard will appear and cursor will begin blinking. I have set the textview as focusable, but it does not gain focus when I call requestFocus(). Is focusing a textview supposed to begin blinking the cursor?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but try  requestfocus attributes in your autocompleteTextview then cursor will be blink..and if you dont want to open keyboard  until user touch the textview..so you can use windowsoftInput attribute in your  manifiest file.

Comment: Yeah, the requestFocus attribute does not appear to have any effect on AutoCompleteTextView.

Comment: @Shane Duffy, have you put windowsoftInput attribute in your manifiest file.?

Comment: I have not. What should I set it as in order to work?

Comment: Just try it...and if doen't work then please post your code, so i can understand what actually you are doing..?

Comment: I am attempting to make an AutoCompleteTextView have a blinking cursor programmatically. Simple as that.